# Google Sign-In ios Refresh token

Tags: ios, google-signin, refresh-token

How can I refresh the access token for Google Sign-In from my `ViewController.swift` class? 
I have tried using the `refreshTokensWithHandler` method but without success.

Can you please provide a code example?